# Checking whether "1" or "0" is at "x" position in powers of 10 sequence (1101001000...) C++

Tags: c++

So I've got this problem to solve. Having a sequence of powers of 10 written one after another, the beginning would look like this: 1101001000... Check whether given number corresponds to "1" or "0" in this sequence.
**First input:** N number defining how many tests are there. **Second input:** N lines with a number to check. **Output:** N numbers that are either "1" or "0".
Example:

> Input:
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 14
>
> 7
>
> 6
>
> Output:
>
> 0 0 1 0

So I've got this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    for (int k = 1; k <= a; k++){
        cin >> b;
        int flag = 0;
        for (int s = 1; s <= b; s++){
            if (((s * (s - 1)) / 2) + 1 == b){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }   
        if (flag == 1)
            cout << "1" << endl;
        else
            cout << "0" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it should work, but the debugger/tester at my school says that time limit has been exceeded, either program takes too long or the program never ends and I'm clueless where's the error. Started programming a month ago so no fancy stuff please.

((s*(s-1))/2)+1 gives "1" places in the sequence.

Comment: does changing the loop to `for(int s=1, r=1; r <=b;++s){r = s * (s - 1) / 2 + 1; if(r == b) ...` help? this helps with not checking for the `s`s that are just too large (the ones that give the position of a `1` that is beyond `b`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're solution is clever. Your idea is to jump over all 1's in the binary string by using a closed formula to get the position of the `s`-th 1 in the sequence. If  the sequence has a 1 at `b`, you find that very quickly by iterating over `s`, since for *some* `s`, the conditition `((s * (s - 1)) / 2) + 1 == b` becomes true. So far it is ok.

However, if the sequence has a 0 at `b`, that condition is *never true*. You never hit a 1, and you only check that in your condition. So if for one value of `s`, the formula is `< b`, and for the next it is `> b`, you jumped over `b`. But you continue the for-loop of `s` until `s > b` and that is way to much time to spend.

So in a nutshell, you need to check for `> b`. If this is the case, you know that the sequence has a 0 at `b`. Simply `break;` out of the loop in this case.

---

You can even improve that by inverting your formula to compute `s` directly from `b`. For this, solve the formula for `s`. [That gives you `s = 0.5*(sqrt(8*b-7)-1)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+s*%28s-1%29%2F2%2B1%3Db+for+s) (Note that the negative solution is irrelevant). This is a computation over the real numbers, so you are going to need floating point numbers for that, and the result is a floating point number, too.

If `s` turns out to be an integral number, you hit a 1, and 0 otherwise. But checking the result to be integral is error-prone (floating point arithmetic introduces some predictable but unavoidable rounding errors). So instead I'd recommend to use the forward formula (the one you already have) with the rounded-down and rounded-up results of this inverted formula. In other words, guess `s` using a floating point inverse formula, use this `s` to check two possible candidates for an integral `s` against your forward formula.

```
float guess_s = 0.5*(sqrt(8*b-7)-1);
int s1 = floor(guess_s); // rounded down
int s2 = s1 + 1;         // rounded up
```

Then check `s1` and `s2` with your formula:

```
if ( ((s1 * (s1 - 1)) / 2) + 1 == b || ((s2 * (s2 - 1)) / 2) + 1 == b )
    cout << "1" << endl;
else
    cout << "0" << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time taken to answer my Q step by step. I clearly missed that `>b` case, which was wasting time. So from what I've understood I only needed another `if` which goes `if (((s * (s - 1)) / 2) + 1 > b) break;` but that didn't help. If I misunderstood then I'm sorry because English is not my native language and it's a bit tough to read about programming.

Comment: Did you double check if your formula is really correct? (I didn't check it. I assumed yours is correct...)

Comment: Hm, the formula seems to be correct. Does your code look like this? http://ideone.com/mhLhy5

Comment: Gives out 1's for 1 2 4 7 11 16 which is correct. The thing that I've noticed is that for numbers above ~1 200 000 000 it gives out 0 where it should be 1 for some, according to wolframalpha. I've just copied it just in case and my school's tester said time limit exceeded. I'll try the 2nd method in a second, but would like to get the 1st one to work if it's possible.

Comment: Ahaa, that seems to be a different problem. Numbers in this range are likely to hit the limit for 32 bit integers, and usually `int` is of that size. You can use 64 bit integers by giving `s` the type `long long` (or `int64_t` when including `<cstdint>`). That is necessary even if `s` itself doesn't hit that limit, because you multiply `s * (s-1)` and this doubles the number of digits in the intermediate result (which is still of type `int` if `s` is of type `int`).

Comment: `long long int s` got it accepted with the `>b` condition. Thank you for your time and thorough explaination of both solutions.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!